# Extjs 4 - Ajax Request 404 error

Tags: url, extjs4, http-status-code-404, ajax-request

I am using `Extjs 4.1.3` and `Symfony1.4` as my php framework, my problem is when using `Ext.Ajax.request` it often returns a 404 error. I say sometimes because other times it pushes through and works fine.

My action basically is checking data entry and inserting data to the database upon clicking save. Checking of data entry tries to communicate with the server with `Ext.Ajax.request`, but like I said it often returns a `404 Error`.

When I go to the link, by using firebug and copy location, it works fine. The link return a json file as expected.

What could be the cause of this? How do I prevent this?

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
    params: {
    agentName       : 'Test'
    },
    url: '/home/CheckEntry',
    timeout: 60000,
    success: function(response, opts) {
    alert('success');
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
            alert('fail');
    }
});
```

**action.class.php** :

```
public functionn executeCheckEntry(sfWebRequest $request)
{
       $returnData = array();
       $agentName = $request->getParameter('agentName');
       try{
        ..............Did validation
        ..............SQL queries
        $return_data['success'] = true;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $return_data['success'] = false;
    }
    die(json_encode($return_data));
  }
```

I hope this is enough.

Comment: Could be a server timeout. How long is a typical response?

Comment: Could you also provide the line where you perform the `Ext.Ajax.request`?

Comment: the response is averaging to 2 seconds only. Okay let me edit my post.

Comment: And also, provide the part of your `actions.class.php` that should handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

"The web site hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

This means that you URL is incorrect.
Possibly `url: '/home/CheckEntry'` is correct as you said that sometimes it works. You need to check if the params that you are passing are correct.